# How to set percentage in a determinate horizontal progress bar

Tags: android, progress-bar

I want to make a custom progress bar, in which I can set percentage values dynamically by the program.

Answer (score 0):

As the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html#setProgress(int)) says, you should use the method:

> void setProgress (int progress)
>
> Sets the current progress to the
>   specified value. Does not do anything if the progress bar is in
>   indeterminate mode.
>
> This method will immediately update the visual position of the
>   progress indicator. To animate the visual position to the target
>   value, use setProgress(int, boolean)}.

So use:

```
progressbar.setProgress(yourProgressValue);
```